# Play Billing Library: What if app fails to give entitlement?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I'm learning Google Play Billing Library to use in my Android App. I sell coin in my app as consumables product.

The flow is: user buy the item, app consume the item, if consume success increment the coin saved in Firestore.

What i want to ask is, **what if increment coin saved in Firestore fails**? Lets say because network or other things. This can cause a problem for users because our app has **already consumed** the item and users don't get their coins.

```
    private fun handleConsumablePurchasesAsync(consumables: List<Purchase>) {
        Timber.d("handleConsumablePurchasesAsync called")
        consumables.forEach { purchase ->
            Timber.d("handleConsumablePurchasesAsync foreach it is $purchase")
            val params = ConsumeParams
                .newBuilder()
                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.purchaseToken)
                .build()
            playStoreBillingClient.consumeAsync(params) { billingResult, purchaseToken ->
                when (billingResult.responseCode) {
                    BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                        purchaseToken.apply { disburseConsumableEntitlements(purchase) }
                    }
                    else -> Timber.w(billingResult.debugMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun disburseConsumableEntitlements(purchase: Purchase) {
        when (purchase.sku) {
            SkuKeys.COINS_5K -> addCoin(5000)
            SkuKeys.COINS_10K -> addCoin(10000)
            SkuKeys.COINS_100K -> addCoin(100000)
            SkuKeys.COINS_500K -> addCoin(500000)
            SkuKeys.COINS_1M -> addCoin(1000000)
            SkuKeys.COINS_2M -> addCoin(2000000)
        }
    }

    //what if this fails?
    private fun addCoin(amount: Long) =
        FirestoreRepository.incrementCoins(FirebaseAuthRepository.currentUserId, amount)
```

How to fix this problem? Are there any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

My proposal,

Consume the item only after writing to Firebase successfully.

When the app is restarted and `queryPurchases()` returns that he still owns the item then try to update in Firebase again

Comment: Then there's a possibility that the app give entitlement multiple times to the user.

Comment: If you update Firebase and then consume the purchase I think it is very unlikely that it will registered twice in Firebase. Also if you use the purchase Token as a key in Firebase then it is impossible for the same purchase to be registered twice.

Comment: What is clear is that if you consume immediately after the purchase, as your code does, if the registration in Firebase fails, it can no longer be fixed, since the in-app billing library does not have any method to retrieve the consumed purchases.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend save the purchases in to database once consumed , You can sync the data from database to firebase .

Once synced you can remove the data from database .

You can trigger a workmanager to sync the data additionally if required .(would be helpful if user kills the app)

This how ever is not secure as anyone with root access can get into database and manupulate with data . You can encrypt the database to make it little more secure but it wont be 100 % fool proof .

If you had a server then purchases could be validated on server side , but for you I can't think of any other solution .

Comment: "If you had a server then purchases could be validated on server side , but for you I can't think of any other solution" Can I use cloud functions?

Comment: I am not sure , I didn't get chance to explore the cloud functions .